# Deleting files with applescript messes up Finder's CoverFlow

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I wrote myself a little script to delete JPG+RAW files by just reviewing my JPG (who loads faster thant CR2).

I've put the following code in an Automator service bound to a keyboard shortcut.

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Finder"
    set myFile to item 1 of input
    set {dispName, nameExt} to the {displayed name, name extension} of myFile
    set extLength to length of nameExt
    set nameWithoutExt to (characters 1 thru ((length of dispName) - extLength) of dispName) -- with the . at the end
    set rawfile to ((parent of myFile as string) & nameWithoutExt & "CR2") as string
    
    set fileIndex to index of myFile
    
    delete every item in {myFile, rawfile}
    
    select file fileIndex of window 1
end tell
end run
```

It works well but it seems to mess with Finder's cover flow : The pictures are not deleted in the coverflow. As you can see i'm a the bottom of the list and coverflow show more picture than there are in the directory (as multiple deletions reduces the size of the list but not the size of the coverflow).

[image]

Any idea why ? Is that maybe a bug in Mavericks ? Or am I missing something ?

Edit : Well I just got the same behavior using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd><-</kbd>. Maybe a bug of Finder in Mavericks ?

Comment: Not relevant to your current problem but more to the JPG+RAW management issue, [here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16401/9161) [are](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16657/9161) [some](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/simple-app-for-viewing-jpg-and-then-deleting-jpgraw-files-simultaneously/5961#5961) links to questions asked on the [Photo.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com) site for a similar situation. I know this doesn't solve your Applescript problem, but it might give you more insight in managing JPG+RAW files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be solved on 10.9.1. I don't have problems anymore after updating the system.

Answer (score 1):

have a look:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/23487157#23487157

or

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5471251

Its an issue from Mavericks (Finder)

Comment: Answers on AD should be more than just a link. Including a link is fine, but please summarize the content of the referenced pages in your answer. The idea is to have answers stand on their own (and also to avoid breaking links as well as having people search for the relevant part themselves on the referenced page)